# How to open settings dialog and sub sections iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, settings

I have a UIAlertController with one Button named "Settings". With a tap on that i want to go to a specific section (e.g Bluetooth) within the settings App. I saw many solutions here, but they all does not work for iOS 11.

Here is my Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Info", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .cancel, handler: { (alert) in
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=Settings&path=General")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I also added under App->Target->Info->URLTypes->URL Schemes: "App-Prefs".
I also tried "prefs"
But nothing is working.

Does anyone have a solution for iOS 11?
Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You just try `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` without App-Prefs

```
if let url = URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        let url =  UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```